# Is is possible to load php functions from a text file?

Tags: php, suphp

I recently updated my server to use SuPHP to increase security.

One downside is that I used to be able to include files from my other domains hosted on my server using absolute paths to the file. This doesn't work anymore.

The file in particular that I include from other domains is my functions file which is huge and used on all my websites. For the sake of maintainability, I've been including a central file rather than uploading the file to each server every time I make changes.

I thought that saving the functions file as plain text and using file_get_contents() across domains might be the right way to go. But apparently this doesn't work.

Is there a way to make it work?

Or is there some other whizz bang function that can help me achieve my goal?

Cheers.

Comment: Are all the websites hosted on the same environment and do you have control over the php.ini?

Comment: A hard link would work across all vhosts/uids.

Comment: Yes, I have php.ini control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need configure open_base_dir in each of your websites vhosts so they are allowed to access the directory where these function files reside. You should put them in a common location.

[open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Another alternative would be to use php_info() to check your include path to see if there is a suitable location already configured where you could place these files, then simply include using include()

[include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

Comment: To add to my answer, I would recommend the latter option, since the include path is much better suited to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've checked phpinfo() and next to include_path it says .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

Is this a suitable location? How would I upload a file at this location?

Comment: You can edit the include_path in ini file to add another path there, seperated by a colon, for example: .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/user/my_php_files

Comment: If you do not have complete access to the server then this path would have to be a location you do have access to.